# Every time after Applying an update is required, why does it happen?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Every time update is required after apply, why does it happen?
that is, there were no changes, immediately after applying, if I execute Plan, then I get a message that needs an implement the changes

```
resource "aws_route_table" "rt_for_private_subnet" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id

  tags = {
    Name = "rt_for_private_subnet"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.private_subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.rt_for_private_subnet.id
}

resource "aws_route" "private_route-1" {
  route_table_id         = aws_route_table.rt_for_private_subnet.id
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  gateway_id             = aws_nat_gateway.my_nat_gw.id
}
```

result:

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_route.private_route-1 will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_route" "private_route-1" {
      + gateway_id             = "nat-098147d3e6b748323"
        id                     = "r-rtb-06e149dbb8685ec071080289494"
      - nat_gateway_id         = "nat-098147d3e6b748323" -> null
        # (4 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

my lab
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6ssB.png)

Comment: What is the config for `aws_nat_gateway.my_nat_gw`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes a remote API offers two different ways to express the same idea.

In this case, `aws_route` wraps the [`ec2:CreateRoute`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateRoute.html) for creating and [`ec2:DescribeRouteTables`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeRouteTables.html) for refreshing. The documentation for `ec2:CreateRoute` says that `GatewayId` is "the ID of an internet gateway or virtual private gateway attached to your VPC", whereas `NatGatewayId` is "The ID of a NAT gateway."

Those two arguments correspond with `gateway_id` and `nat_gateway_id` respectively in Terraform, so it seems that your configuration is incorrect because you've assigned a NAT Gateway ID to the `gateway_id` argument instead of the `nat_gateway_id` argument.

Unfortunately the EC2 API seems to tolerate that mistake by just silently moving the value from `gateway_id` to `nat_gateway_id`, rather than by returning an error, and so when the AWS provider subsequently calls `ec2:DescribeRouteTables` to refresh this route it finds that the object doesn't match what you wrote in your configuration, and so it proposes to update the object to match the configuration again.

You can avoid this problem by assigning the NAT Gateway ID to the correct argument -- that is, to use `nat_gateway_id` instead of `gateway_id`:

```
resource "aws_route" "private_route-1" {
  route_table_id         = aws_route_table.rt_for_private_subnet.id
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  nat_gateway_id         = aws_nat_gateway.my_nat_gw.id
}
```

---

Technically it's part of the responsibility of a Terraform provider to know when there are two ways of writing the same idea in a remote API and to hide that difference from you so that your changes can still converge as you expected. However, the `hashicorp/aws` provider seems to be missing a rule to handle this situation.

The AWS provider repository has a very old [issue #158](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/158) discussing this problem which was closed due to inactivity, so you might choose to open a new issue capturing your example of the problem and linking back to that older issue so that the provider maintainers can see that this problem still exists in more recent versions of the provider.

Comment: Thank you for this!  This has been driving me nuts for months now.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong attribute in your `route` resource.

`+ gateway_id             = "nat-098147d3e6b748323"`

In the above, Terraform says it will add a new NAT with a different ID. That is what the `+` indicates.

`- nat_gateway_id         = "nat-098147d3e6b748323" -> null`

In the above, Terraform is saying that it will delete the resource attached to the `nat_gateway_id`, but the `null` is saying that no resource is added to the attribute.

It is advisable you change the attribute from `gateway_id` to `nat_gateway_id` in your route resource.

To confirm that you are using the wrong attribute, do a

`terraform state show aws_route.private_route-1`

Answer (score 0):

Terraform is a declarative tool that aims to maintain a desired state for infrastructure resources. When you make changes to your Terraform code and apply those changes, Terraform compares the desired state of the resources with the current state of the resources in the target environment.

In your specific case, Terraform is detecting a change in the gateway_id attribute of the aws_route.private_route-1 resource. The gateway_id value is changing from "nat_gateway_id" to "nat-098147d3e6b748323". This change is causing Terraform to generate an update in-place action for the aws_route.private_route-1 resource.

It's important to understand that Terraform only makes changes to resources that are necessary to bring the desired state into alignment with the current state. In this case, even though the aws_route_table and aws_route_table_association resources are not changing, Terraform still needs to update the aws_route resource to ensure that the entire desired state is correctly applied.

In summary, Terraform's behavior is expected, and it's a core feature of the tool to maintain infrastructure as code. Whenever you make changes to your code, Terraform will compare the current state of your resources with the desired state and make updates as necessary.

Comment: After the command 'Apply', after 2 seconds I run the 'Plan', that is, 100% of me or someone else does not make a change at this time.